# How to get telegram user info from telegram game

Tags: bots, telegram

I have created a game bot to present my simple h5 game in telegram. I wonder how to get the telegram user info who is playing my h5 game?

What i have done:

- created bot to reply game to telegram
- created bot to handle callback message from telegram play game button(the callback message `from` will always be my bot)
- the chatgpt said telegram will carry user info into the game url, then i try to print game url when game opened in telegram, but nothing got
- viewed the game integration doc but no related infomation found

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the callback query carries the user info in the top field `from` like below:

```json
{
    callback_query: {
        id: "697xxxxxx622",
        from: {
            id: 162xxxx327,
            is_bot: false,
            first_name: "Test",
            username: "xxxx",
            language_code: "xxxx"
        },
        message: {}
    }
}
```